# ActiveMQ failover transport - producers/consumers work on different hosts

Tags: connection, jms, activemq-classic, failover

ConnectionURL

```
failover:(tcp://broker1:61616,tcp://broker2:61616)?andomize=false&jms.useAsyncSend=false&jms.dispatchAsync=false&maxReconnectAttempts=30&maxReconnectDelay=3000&jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1000
```

Scenario:

Producer puts a message to the queue_1

```
create connection
put message
close connection
```

Listener (auto_ack) - has a long lived connection since this is a listener

```
retrieves the message
puts it in queue_2 (client_ack)
```

Thread that runs periodically

```
create connection
retrieves everything from queue_2
processes messages
ack messages
close connection
```

The problem - broker_1 goes down. FailoverTransport redirects traffic to broker_2. All three pieces (Procuder, Listener and Thread) work with broker_2).
broker_1 is brought back. Procuder and Thread connect to broker_1. Listener remains on broker_2. Surprisingly - the onMessage is called when message arives to queue_1 on broker_1, but listener puts the message to queue_2 on broker_2.

How can I instruct the listener to reconnect to broker_1 once its operational again? Or should I rather force Producer and Thread work with broker_2 as long as it's operational?

Answer (score 0):

If the brokers are networked together it will only matter if there is an imbalance of connections. If your traffic volume and number of connections is moderate, you don't necessarily have an issue.

ActiveMQ supports automatic rebalance of clients based on a "best guess".

1. Configure a network of brokers
2. Update your openwire transport connector to use 'updateClusterClients="true"' and 'rebalanceClusterClients="true"'

ref: http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html

ref: http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html

If you want administrators to be able to manually rebalance connections, the Media Driver Integrated Console provides a way to do that: https://mediadriver.com/software/

Disclosure: I head up product development at Media Driver.